# Finding the number of lines intersection

Tags: geometry, algorithms, permutations

It is required to develop the following algorithm:

> **Input**: $n$ non vertical lines (in the form $(a,b)$ indicating $y=ax+b$) and a number $a\in \mathbb{R}$
>
> **Output**: how many intersection of the lines lie to the left of the line $x=a$
>
> This has to be done in $O(n \log(n))$. The algorithm is trivial for
>   $O(n^2)$, but  we can use an additional fact:
>
> **Fact:** There exists an algorithm that given a permutation $\pi$, computes the number of inversions in $O(n \log(n))$. An inversion of a
>   permutation is a pair of indices $i<j$ such that $\pi(i)>\pi(j)$

My idea to solve this problem in the required time is to somehow order the lines in an array, then permute them and using the fact, our algorithm will give the correct output.
I can think of the concept of duality that could come in handy, where for a given line $l: y=ax+b$ we have the dual point $l^*=(a,-b)$, but I can't think of a clever way to permute the input lines to solve this problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, assume there are no intersections happening exactly at $x=x_0$ (your vertical line, I don't want to use $a$ because I will use it for the slopes of the lines). Order the lines by their $y$ coordinate at $x=x_0$ and denote them by
$$\ell_1=\{a_1x+b_1\}<\ell_2<\ldots<\ell_n.$$
Now, at the left of the first intersection the lines will be ordered in another way, giving a permutation of their order
$$\ell_{\sigma(1)}<'\ldots<'\ell_{\sigma(n)}.$$
The number of inversions of the permutation $\sigma$ is exactly the number of intersections.

---

Algorithmically:

1. Order the lines based on their value at $x_0$, that is $\ell_i<\ell_j$ if, and only if $a_ix_0+b_i < a_jx_0+b_j$.
2. Order the lines based on their order at the left of the first intersection, that is $\ell_i>\ell_j$ if, and only if $a_i<a_j$ or $a_i=a_j$ and $b_i<b_j$.
3. Compare the two orders to find $\sigma$.
4. Use the given algorithm to compute the number of inversions.

Notice that the first two steps just require a sorting, which you can do with e.g. mergesort (which is $O(n\log n)$), step $3$ should be $O(n)$, and the last step is obviously $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Is this argument using the view of projective geometry?

Comment: @mvw I'm... not sure? I don't think so.

Comment: @mvw But if you have an iterpretation of my algorithm in terms of projective geometry, feel free to post it. I'm interested.

Comment: The value of a line at infinity for a non constant line is infinity, or?

Comment: shouldn't i look for the values the lines have at $-\inf$ since we are looking for intersections to the left of $x=x_0$?

Comment: @mvw I'm not really looking at the value of the line at infinity, just at which line is "above" which other line. It's badly explained, but I don't know how to clarify it. I hope the algorithm I posted in the second part of my answer makes it understandable.

Comment: Projective geometry came to my mind, because it adds "far elements" at infinity.

Comment: @SimoneGuggiari Yes, of course. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: @SimoneGuggiari Now it should be correct.

Comment: @mvw You can probably reformulate all in terms of elements of $\mathbb{RP}^3$ (remark: the lines are not through the origin, so $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is not enough) ad work there, but I think it would just be an overcomplication.

Comment: Make that *"2. Order the lines by their slope, ..."* to avoid any ambiguity about evaluating a point at infinity. The *logic* stays the same; only, instead of "ordering at infinity", it becomes "ordering at $x$ coordinate smaller than any intersection".

Comment: @NominalAnimal That's not enough, as two lines could have the same slope but different $b$'s...

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: You misunderstand. I didn't mean you change the logic of the algorithm at all. (In other words, you'd still have the first ordered set sorted by the $y$ coordinates at $x=x_0$, and the second ordered set sorted primarily by the slopes, secondarily (for equal slopes) by the constant coefficient.) I only meant that the argument about *infinity* is misleading, and completely avoidable. The algorithm remains exactly the same. The only thing that changes is the reasoning behind it: "at infinity" becomes "to the left of the first possible intersection".

Comment: @NominalAnimal Oh, I see. Yeah, it is a better formulation. I will edit my answer. Thanks.